# JavaFX - Switching Scenes in an EventHandler

Tags: java, sql-server, javafx, fxml

I'm creating a signUp page and once the user clicks signUp button I want the scene to switch to my budgetView layout. (Which is an FXML file).

I have tried extending my sign up controller with the Application class, and overrode the start method, but it kept giving me an error. This is the route my teacher tried to get me to try. I have also created another primaryStage in my controller and that worked, but my previous scene didn't close it just created another AnchorPane on top of the existing SignUp Scene. I want to just switch from one FXML view to another, when the event handler is initiated and successful.

Event Handler

```
try {
                SignUpDAO.insertUser(txtFieldEmail.getText(), txtFieldFirst.getText(), txtFieldLast.getText(),
                        passFieldPassword.getText());
                resultArea.setText("User inserted! \n");

                // SUPPOSED TO OPEN NEW SCENE THROWS
                // Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException:
                // java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
//              start(primaryStage);
```

Overridden Start Method

```
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
            AnchorPane budgetLayout = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainLayout.fxml"));


            // SignUp Layout
            Scene scene1 = new Scene(budgetLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
            primaryStage.show();
```